# When are the closed convex subsets countable intersections of halfspaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-polytopes, hilbert-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

For what kind of topological vector spaces (separable maybe?) are the closed convex subsets *countable* intersections of halfspaces.

I've seen somewhere that it's true for separable Hilbert spaces, but without proof or reference. Is there a reference on this fact (and related questions)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is addressed in:

*Borwein, Jonathan M.; Vanderwerff, Jon D.*, [**Constructible convex sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/B:SVAN.0000023393.75251.05), Set-Valued Anal. 12, No. 1-2, 61-77 (2004). [ZBL1059.46056](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1059.46056).

Comment: I pulled up this paper but I could not discern a clear answer.  Prop 3.3 seems the closest match and says that if some $B_{X^*}$ thingy satisfies a Corson compact thingy then "every closed convex subset in X is constructible if and only if there exists at least one closed bounded convex constructible set in X."  I'm not sure what other (Banach space?) assumptions X is assumed to have.  I don't even know if $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies the Corson-and-$B_{X^*}$ thingy. This paper could have been more helpful if the authors had written a few sentences to give down-to-earth interpretations.

Comment: **Note to functional analysis mathematicians: Please tell us if your results hold for $\mathbb{R}^n$**. Anyway I can likely prove the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case myself but it would have been nice to have a reference,  at least the case when a set is closed, bounded, and convex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ it seems easy-to-prove (the case of just closed and convex seems more tricky).

Comment: On the positive side, the paper seems to be well written with a simple and easy flow, it just uses a lot of loaded terminology that is hard for me to plug into. I would have to read the paper in detail from start to finish, looking up on wikipedia every 5 minutes to get the different terminology, to be confident in applying the results even to basic spaces like $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 4):

Those authors have a book on the topic that gives the following more down-to-earth interpretation:

J. M. Borwein and J. D. Vanderwerff, *Convex Functions: Constructions, Characterizations and Counterexamples* Cambridge University Press, 2010.
https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/resources/jon/Preprints/Books/CUP/cup-final.pdf

- Just before Proposition 7.5.6 it defines: "A (closed convex) set in a
  Banach space is *constructible* if it is representable as the intersection of *countably* many closed half spaces."
- Proposition 7.5.6 in the book: "A closed convex subset [of a Banach space] containing the origin is constructible if and only if its polar is weak*-separable."
- The book immediately follows Proposition 7.5.6 with this interpretation: "In particular, all closed convex subsets of a separable [Banach] space are constructible."

The bracketed phrases in the above quotes are my own additions. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a separable Banach space, it works for all closed and convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.